# Hitting a GET endpoint from a java class

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a REST API with the following URL in one Java project:
http://localhost:9094/start

```
@RequestMapping("/start")
 public void start() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("started");
}
```

I am trying to hit this URL from another Java project

```
private boolean start(){
    try{
        httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9094/start");

        System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
        httpClient.close();

        return response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK;

    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        logger.error("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}


public void testing(){
   if(start()){
      System.out.println("Done");
   }
}
```

For some reason, I can't seem to get "Done" printed or started. I have no idea why.

Solved:
Stupid mistake, just forgot to add authorization headers.

Comment: Is your calling java class is spring based or plain java??

Comment: Are you able to see the response when you browse this url using a browser http://localhost:9094/start If not please check your basepath of your project

Comment: just a thought. why not use spring's rest template ?

Comment: Don't include your answer inside the question, post it as a separate answer and mark it as accepted. However, this particular answer is of no use as you didn't include enough detail to make it possible to figure it out that this was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would certainly would go for RestTemplate from spring. Make sure as well the path is correct, and your Controller does not have a mapping as well.

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 public void callHello() {
  restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9094/start",null);
    }
```

And you can specify the exact RequestMethod of your rest api as well.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "start",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void call() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
```